# Activate the validation of a lightning: checkboxGroup when loading the page

Tags: lightning, validation

I am finishing the last details of my form and I was wondering that when loading the page, the validation of the lightning: checkboxGroup can be activated?

[image]

since I have to activate the validation manually

[image]

Comment: What do you mean manually? What are you hoping to do?

Comment: That the validation is activated when loading the page as shown in the second image